# How do I restrict access to a Git folder on Android to only certain apps without a password check?

Tags: applications, security, file-management

I want to secure a git folder on an Android device so that only specific apps do have access to its content of it. In the best case, there shouldn't even be a password check. I have sensitive data which should be easily accessible between my devices. Using git is the best option in my case, so switching to another option is not wished.

On my Huawei Nova 5T (non-rooted), there is no integrated option to encrypt the data or anything similar. I tried to use Shelter, but that seems not to do the job. Using X-plore file manager I've got a vault to store files, but I can't see the location on my phone so I couldn't use it for git + being asked for a key isn't as comfortable as I like to have it.

Comment: The Android storage system does not provide on option to share data with certain apps. Apps can have app private data only accessible by the app itself or a more or less public on the shared storage. The only way to keep the data private to an app but give other apps access would be implementing a content provider but that only works on a oer-fike basis and if I remember correctly not with random-access read/write but just read sequentially the whole file. But that is the programming level, I don't know what apps exists that make use of this meachnism.

Comment: So is there no way to store data at a shared storage which you can access by multiple devicec which is secured in anyway? Specifically I use i.e. Obsidian to store private data or my keepass vault. If I don't use something like git I would have to manage my passwords on 3 devices and so on. Maybe a SSD-card can help as an access-controll wall?

Comment: I prefer specialized apps. For passwords there are very good programs available. I prefer KeepassX compatible apps like "Keepass 2 Android". The key store file can be stored in any non-encrypted syn service like dropbox (directly in the app) if you use the Keepass feature to use a key file in addition to the password. If you keep the static keyfile private (no cloud only direct transfer via USB) this makes your keepass password wallet "unhackable" by guessing the password as also the file is necessary.